# How to Read XML to DataSet if XElement has an Attribute?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm unable to read XML to DataSet if XElement has an Attribute ?

XML is like:

```
<User>
    <Name>AAA</Name>
    <EmailId>aaa@mail.com</EmailId>
    <Salary Unit="$">5000</Salary>
</User>
```

And C# code like:

```
XmlTextReader xReader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath(xmlPath)); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
ds.ReadXml(xReader, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
```

Dataset doesnot have the Salary column.

Comment: You can use LINQ to XML as long as your XML and set of columns does not change.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please post a sample code ?

Comment: just look at XDocument examples

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var schema = new XElement("User",
    xel.Descendants().Select(d => new XElement(d.Name))
    );
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(schema.CreateReader(), XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
```